# Do I need a Russian visa for transit?

Tags: visas, transit-visas, russia, swedish-citizens

As a Swedish citizen I need a visa to travel to Russia but not to Malaysia.

If I book 2 separate flights:

Stockholm → Moscow → Stockholm
Moscow → Kuala Lumpur → Moscow

I would fly Stockholm → Moscow → Kuala Lumpur and back.

I do not intend to leave the Moscow airport, would I still need a Russian visa?
If yes, would it be a normal visit visa to Russia?

Comment: @VMAtm I'm just wondering if there would be any problem at the time of boarding to go to Moscow as the bookings are made separately.

Comment: @maja You'll have the ticket for the connecting flight so you'll be able to prove you're connecting, I don't see a problem.

Comment: Do you plan to stay airside for the whole period in Russia? I.e. not go to immigration, go to connections directly, avoid collecting luggage, registering electronically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In theory, you should **not** need a visa. As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=ru&SECTION=vi&SUBSECTION=tw&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the database used by airlines:

> Visa exemptions: holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.

In my experience, however, in practice many check-in clerks and gate staff (incorrectly) interpret this as "Holders of onward tickets **in the same booking** for a max. transit time of 24 hours", and are thus likely to deny you boarding without a visa. One reason being that, if you miss your connection due to a delay, you're not covered by the airline and would be stranded at the Moscow airport, in which case your inbound carrier could be forced to send you back, a situation they want to avoid at all costs.

Furthermore, if you have checked-in luggage, it may very well not be checked through, in which case you will need a transit visa to pick it up and re-check it, which requires clearing immigration (both in- and outbound)

Contact Menzies Aviation at Arlanda at 08-797 80 84 (they're the ones checking you in, and, I think, checking you at the gate) to find out the arrangements regarding checked-in luggage (if you have any) and how they enforce the onward connection rule.

If you do end up having to apply for a visa, then no, you do not want "a normal visit visa", but a **double-entry transit visa**

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in [linked question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49823/10-hour-layover-in-moscow-russia-do-i-need-a-transit-visa/19), you need tickets for your next flight ready to show at the moment you arriving at the `SVO`. Make sure that:

- Your airport is `SVO` in Moscow
- You have the same airport for your flights
- Your layover is less than 24 hours

and you're fine. Otherwise, as @AE said, you need a transit visa.